# How to get a photo from Server and display it in Image Control for Wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using the below code. I just dont know why it is not working. The error msg is : Unspecified error on this : bmp.SetSource(ms).

I am not familiar with HttpWebRequest for Wp7. Would appreciate your help to solve this problem. Thanks.

```
enter code here


 private void LoadPic()
    {
   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://xxxxxx/MyImage.jpg");
        NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Pwd");
        req.Credentials = creds;
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetStatusesCallBack), req);
    }

    public void GetStatusesCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.EndGetResponse(result);
            Stream myStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            int len = (int)myStream.Length;

            byte[] byt = new Byte[len];
            myStream.Read(byt, 0, len);
            myStream.Close();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byt);
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(ms);

                image1.Source = bmp;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
   }
```

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932353/c-bitmap-images-byte-arrays-and-streams

Comment: I agree with Jason; the question he linked probably contains your solution.  The error message may be different because of different platforms, but the problem is in the way you are using Stream.Read().

Comment: @Jason: Saw your link. I try before, No can do. It seems HttpWebRequest is working diff in silverlight for wp7. I hv been out of luck. Thank anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to copy the response stream to a byte array and then to a MemoryStream?  If not, you can just do the following:

```
    Stream myStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(myStream);
        image1.Source = bmp;
    });
```

If you have to do the copy for some reason, you will need to fill the buffer in a loop:

```
    Stream myStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    int contentLength = (int)myStream.Length;
    byte[] byt = new Byte[contentLength];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < contentLength; )
    {
        int len = myStream.Read(byt, pos, contentLength - pos);
        if (len == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Upload aborted.");
        }
        pos += len;
    }
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byt);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // same as above
    });
```

Second part adapted (slightly) from [C# bitmap images, byte arrays and streams!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932353/c-bitmap-images-byte-arrays-and-streams).

Comment: Thank. But it does not work. I have error msg : Invalid cross-thread access. This refer to the way silverlight handling UI. I am totallly not sure how it works.

Comment: @Milk What line is causing that exception?  I am not very experienced in WP7, but I know that you can't operate on a BitmapImage object outside of the UI thread, which is why the three statements related to it must be inside the Dispatcher invocation.  See this thread for a similar issue with WriteableBitmap: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/5b596520-a07e-43e4-bff8-d5e172f3adf7.  At any rate, the HTTP response stream does contain a valid image in my tests.

Comment: This code works in my WP7 app, So this issue might be something related to the Credential not working? Or your myStream.Length might be zero?

Comment: @Jobi Jpy: Good to hear that. are yu using the same code or something else? Do you mind to post the code if it is different from the above. I like to find out why. Thanks